# The contrapositive of "If there is an odd prime number, then for no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there is no $y \in \mathbb{N}$, that $y > x$"

Tags: logic

I have a statement of the form $p\to q$, and I have to find $\lnot q\to \lnot p$ (the contrapositive) so it means the same.

The statement is:

> If there is an odd prime number, then for no $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there is no $y \in \mathbb{N}$, that $y > x$.

Which of the following is correct?

a.) If there is no odd prime number, then for  every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $y \in \mathbb{N}$ so that, $y>x$.

b.) If there is an odd prime number, then for every $x \in \mathbb{N}$ there is an $y \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $y>x$.

c.) If there are $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $y \in \mathbb{N}$, so that $y>x$, then there is no odd prime number.

d.) If there are $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $y \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $y\leq x$, then there is an odd prime number.

There could be more correct answears.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This will be easier if we first convert the statement to the proper set theoretic notation.

> If there is an odd prime number, then for no $x\in \mathbb{N}$ there is no $y\in\mathbb{N}$, that $y>x$.

We may express this as follows:

$$ \exists \textrm{ prime } p, p\textrm{ odd } \implies \neg \,\exists \,x\in \mathbb{N}, \neg\, \exists \, y\in \mathbb{N}, y>x $$

Then the contrapositive has the form

\begin{align}
\,&\neg\left(\neg \,\exists \,x\in \mathbb{N}, \neg\, \exists \, y\in \mathbb{N}, y>x \right) &\implies  \neg\left(\exists \textrm{ prime } p, p\textrm{ odd }\right)\\
\vdash \,\,\,\,& \exists\, x\in \mathbb{N}, \neg \,\exists\,y\in \mathbb{N}, y>x &\implies \forall \textrm{ odd } p, \neg \, p \textrm{ prime}\\
\vdash\,\,\,\,&\exists \,x\in\mathbb{N}, \,\forall \,y\in \mathbb{N}, \neg\, (y>x) &\implies \forall \textrm{ odd } p, \neg \, p \textrm{ prime}\\
\vdash \,\,\,\,&\exists\,x\in \mathbb{N},\forall \, y\in \mathbb{N},\, y\leq x &\implies \forall \textrm{ odd } p, \neg \, p \textrm{ prime}\\
\end{align}

So, what do we have? Something like...

> If there exists an $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $y\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $y\leq x$, then there is no prime odd number.

or

> If there exists an $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $y\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $\neg\,(y>x)$, then every odd number is not prime.

or something else to that effect.